# Days between two dates with grorian calendar in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, date

I am trying to calculate the differences in days between two dates by pressing a button.
This is what I've done

```
public void CalcolaG(View view)
{


    long DataI1;
    long DataF1;
    long oneDay; 
    long Risultato1;
    //
    Risultato1 = 0;
    //
    EditText DataI = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.DataI);
    EditText DataF = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.DataF);
    TextView Risultato = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Risultato); 


    DataI1 = Long.parseLong(DataI.getText().toString());
    DataF1 = Long.parseLong(DataF.getText().toString());
    oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    Risultato1 = (DataF1 - DataI1) / oneDay;

   //
    Risultato.setText(Double.toString(Risultato1));
}


}
```

But when I press the button nothing happens, where's the error?

Comment: Where do you bind your method with the button click event?

Comment: `Long.parseLong(DataI.getText().toString())` implies that your user enters the date as a timestamp? You probably should use a DatePicker to select the date.

Comment: And could you please use the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367).

Comment: Ok, solved this thing, how can i input dates? This seems not works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add `android:onClick="CalcolaG"` to the button tag in your layout XML? Also, if there's `import android.R` in import statements delete it.